# SCP over a ssh tunnel

Tags: ssh, sublimetext3, scp, remote-desktop, tunneling

I am connecting to a remote server over a ssh tunnel like so :
ssh -p 12345 -L 7777:90.10.10.10:6666 user1@dev-remote.example.com

These details might be unnecessary but just in case :
After i run this command i open a remote desktop session using remmina for linux.
and there i put details : localhost:7777 and i can connect to my remote desktop ( a vm basically ).
Now in the remote desktop i have to use putty and put details as :
www-dev-pqr-xyz:22 and then i can finally mount a network drive and then work on the codebase

Is there a way i can scp file from remote to my local machine and configure my sublime text in such a way so that whenever i make any changes it goes to remote server via remote desktop, sorry if i miss some concepts here, i am new to ssh tunneling.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

No need to "scp", you can mount remote filesystems over ssh using [sshfs](https://github.com/libfuse/sshfs), from the description:

> SSHFS allows you to mount a remote filesystem using SFTP. Most SSH servers support and enable this SFTP access by default, so SSHFS is very simple to use - there's nothing to do on the server-side.

It is also straight-forward to use: `sshfs [user@]hostname:[directory] mountpoint`

Comment: so what do you suggest i should type in terminal. The mounted netwrok drive is Z: ```ssh -p 12345 -L 7777:90.10.10.10:6666 user1@dev-remote.example.com```